# slickslider - slide to show 4.5 showing half image on left side. I want it on right side

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

I'm using slick slider. I need to show half of the next image in the right side corner. So, I'm using slide to show as 4.5 But the half image is displaying in the left side corner of the slickslider. Is there any option to change it to the right side[

```js
$('.slider-nav').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4.5,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      dots: false,
      centerPadding: '30px',
      nextArrow: '<div class="nav-arrow slick-next slick-arrow"><i class="icon-rightarrow-lg"></i></div>',
      prevArrow: '<button class="nav-arrow slick-prev slick-arrow leftarrow"><i class="icon-leftarrow-md" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',      
      focusOnSelect: true,
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNyOM.jpg)

Comment: try `centerMode: true`. using a half value in `slidesToShow` can be a bit buggy so I suggest you play with `centerMode: true` and `centerPadding` values